# How to disable a single 3rd party module plugin class in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, class

3rd party module has a file in the following location: **Amasty/Xsearch/Plugin/Framework/View/Page/Config.php**.

This file contains a class like this:

```
<?php

namespace Amasty\Xsearch\Plugin\Framework\View\Page;

use \Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config as NativeConfig;

class Config
{
```

I would like to disable this single class completely and use the Magento class instead. What is the best approach?

**UPDATE**:

This is the di.xml for the 3rd party module where `Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config` is injected:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * @author Amasty Team
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2019 Amasty (https://www.amasty.com)
 * @package Amasty_Xsearch
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Amasty\Xsearch\Block\Autocomplete">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="catalogLayer" xsi:type="object">Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Search</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Result">
        <plugin name="Amasty_Xsearch::result-count" type="Amasty\Xsearch\Plugin\CatalogSearch\Block\Result" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config">
        <plugin name="Amasty_Xsearch::noindex-nofollow" type="Amasty\Xsearch\Plugin\Framework\View\Page\Config" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\Router\NoRouteHandler">
        <plugin name="Amasty_Xsearch::404_redirect" type="Amasty\Xsearch\Plugin\Framework\App\Router\NoRouteHandler" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection">
        <plugin name="Amasty_Xsearch::SortingMethodsProcessor" type="Amasty\Xsearch\Plugin\Catalog\Product\CollectionPlugin"/>
    </type>

    <type name="Amasty\Shopby\Model\ResourceModel\Fulltext\Collection">
        <plugin name="Amasty_Xsearch::SortingMethodsProcessor-shopby" type="Amasty\Xsearch\Plugin\Catalog\Product\CollectionPlugin"/>
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Search\Helper\Data">
        <plugin name="Amasty_Xsearch::generate_seo_url" type="Amasty\Xsearch\Plugin\Search\Helper\Data"/>
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index">
        <plugin name="Amasty_Xsearch::redirect_to_seo_url" type="Amasty\Xsearch\Plugin\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index"/>
    </type>

    <type name="Amasty\Shopby\Controller\Search\Result\Index">
        <plugin name="Amasty_Xsearch::redirect_to_seo_url_shopby" type="Amasty\Xsearch\Plugin\CatalogSearch\Controller\Result\Index"/>
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Search\Model\Query">
        <plugin name="Amasty_Xsearch::save_query" type="Amasty\Xsearch\Plugin\Search\Model\Query" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="amasty_xsearch" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Amasty\Xsearch\Controller\Router</item>
                    <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">45</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>

    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config\Renderer">
        <plugin name="Amasty_Xsearch::make-css" type="Amasty\Xsearch\Plugin\View\Page\Config\Renderer" />
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: Show your di.xml

Comment: Added as requested :)

Comment: Not this one. Where Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config inject as plugin that di.xml.

Comment: I'm sorry for this, is this the correct one?

Comment: Check answer and adjust this your custom module.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily disable plugin. Try the following way:

Following code add your di.xml in global scope that means location should be **YourVendor/YourModule\etc\di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config">
    <plugin name="Amasty_Xsearch::noindex-nofollow" type="Amasty\Xsearch\Plugin\Framework\View\Page\Config" disabled="true"/>
</type>
```

Your custom module should load after **Amasty_Xsearch** module. So added sequence in your module.xml like:

```
<sequence>
    <module name="Amasty_Xsearch"/>
</sequence>
```

Comment: hymmm... I get this `Element 'sequence': This element is not expected.` when trying to compile :/

Comment: Ahhh added it in the wrong file. Let me check now ....

Comment: Worked perfectly :) Lesson learned!